# Add comments next to files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, comments

I'm interested in simply adding a comment next to my files in Linux (Ubuntu). An example would be:

```
info user ... my_data.csv           Raw data which was sent to me.
info user ... my_data_cleaned.csv   Raw data with duplicates filtered.
info user ... my_data_top10.csv     Cleaned data with only top 10 values selected for each ID.
```

So sort of the way you can comment commits in Git. I don't particularly care about searching on these tags, filtering them etc. Just seeings them when I list files in a directory. Bonus if the comments/tags follow the document around as I copy or move it.

Comment: You probably want to create a shell script wrapper around `ls` that takes data from ls and inserts your text at the end of each line.  After that, you would remap ls -l to your shell script through bash aliases.

Comment: So, @marc, do you mind to elaborate how it went with this project / idea? Have you found a solution? Did you set up your own (and maybe open sourced it somewhere)? :)

Answer (score 4):

Most filesystem types support extended attributes where you could store comments.

So for example to create a comment on "foo.file":

```
xattr -w user.comment "This is a comment" foo.file
```

The attributes can be copied/moved with the file just be aware that many utilities require special options to copy the extended attributes.

Then to list files with comments use a script or program that grabs the extended attribute. Here is a simple example to use as a starting point, it just lists the files in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -1 | while read -r FILE; do
   comment=`xattr -p user.comment "$FILE" 2>/dev/null`
   if [ -n "$comment" ]; then
      echo "$FILE Comment: $comment"
   else
      echo "$FILE"
   fi
done
```

The xattr command is really slow and poorly written (it doesn't even return error status) so I suggest something else if possible. Use `setfattr` and `getfattr` in a more complex script than what I have provided. Or maybe a custom `ls` command that is aware of the user.comment attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This is a moderately serious challenge. Basically, you want to add attributes to files, keep the attributes when the file is copied or moved, and then modify ls to display the values of these attributes.

So, here's how I would attack the problem.

1) Store the information in a sqlLite database. You can probably get away with one table. The table should contain the complete path to the file, and your comment. I'd name the database something like ~/.dirinfo/dirinfo.db. I'd store it in a subfolder, because you may find later on that you need other information in this folder. It'd be nice to use inodes rather than pathnames, but they change too frequently. Still, you might be able to do something where you store both the inode and the pathname, and retrieve by pathname only if the retrieval by inode fails, in which case you'd then update the inode information.

2) write a bash script to create/read/update/delete the comment for a given file.

3) Write another bash function or script that works with ls. I wouldn't call it "ls" though, because you don't want to mess with all the command line options that are available to ls. You're going to be calling ls always as `ls -1` in your script, possibly with some sort options, such as -t and/or -r. Anyway, your script will call `ls -1` and loop through the output, displaying the file name, and the comment, which you'll look up using the script from 2). You may also want to add file size, but that's up to you.

4) write functions to replace mv and cp (and ln??). These would be wrapper functions that would update the information in your table, and then call the regular Unix versions of these commands, passing along any arguments received by the functions (i.e. "$@"). If you're really paranoid, you'd also do it for things like scp, which can be used (inefficiently) to copy files locally. Still, it's unlikely you'll catch all the possibilities. What if someone else does a mv on your file, who doesn't have the function you have? What if some script moves the file by calling /bin/mv? You can't easily get around these kinds of issues.

Or if you really wanted to get adventurous, you'd write some C/C++ code to do this. It'd be faster, and honestly not all that much more challenging, provided you understand fork() and exec(). I can't recall whether sqlite has a C API. I assume it does. You'd have to tangle with that, too, but since you only have one database, and one table, that shouldn't be too challenging.

You could do it in perl, too, but I'm not sure that it would be that much easier in perl, than in bash. Your actual code isn't that complex, and you're not likely to be doing any crazy regex stuff or string manipulations. There are just lots of small pieces to fit together.

Doing all of this is much more work than should be expected for a person answering a question here, but I've given you the overall design. Implementing it should be relatively easy if you follow the design above and can live with the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

create a 'dirdsc' file

```
# dirdsc
#!/bin/env bash

SCRDIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

source $SCRDIR/colors

DSCFIL=".dsc"
if [ ! -f "$DSCFIL" ]; then
   touch $DSCFIL
fi

echo

for FILNME in $(ls -1 --group-directories-first $@ )
do
    ATTVAR="$WHITE"
    if [ -d "$FILNME" ]; then
        ATTVAR=$GREEN
    fi

    ENTTXT=$( grep "^$FILNME" .dsc )

    DSCTXT=""
    if [[ !  "$ENTTXT" == "" ]]; then
        DSCTXT=$( echo "$ENTTXT" | cut -b 51- )
    fi
    FILNME=$(echo "$ATTVAR $FILNME $NORMAL" | cut -b 1-50)
    printf   "%-50s %-50s\n" "$FILNME" "$DSCTXT"
done

echo
```

Then...

```
echo  "l       : List directories and files with description if they have one"
alias l="$SCRDIR/dirdsc"
```

Then create a .dsc file with descriptions, descriptions start at column 50

```
README.md                                         Read me before start
api                                               Api source code
bin                                               Convenience Cmds &  alias
clt                                               Feign clients for Entities
doc                                               Docs & Blogs about this
dta                                               Persistent volumes
ent                                               Entities projects 
inf                                               Infraestructdocker files
k8s                                               Helm charts&Kustomize yaml
lab                                               Lab projects to learn    
lib                                               Utility Libraries projects
msc                                               Miscelaneas
sql                                               SQL Scripts
svc                                               Services pods
tol                                               Tools
uip                                               User interface pods
```

now use l to list files to get:

```
README.md                                         Read me before start
api                                               Api source code
bin                                               Convenience Commands & 
....
```

With colourized output
[Desidered ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkcaG.png)